# net::ERR_TIMED_OUT flutter web http package

Tags: flutter, dart, http, restful-url

I use the HTTP package to post a request to the server and handle errors but there is a `net::ERR_TIMED_OUT` error when sending a request to the server which I can not figure out how to handle it.
Here is my send request

```
  Future<Session> login(String username, String password) async {
    final request = Uri.https(
      _baseUrlGeocoding,
      '/login',
      {'email': username.trim(), 'password': password},
    );

    try {
      final response = await _httpClient.post(request);
      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        throw LoginRequestServerFailure();
      }

      final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

      if (responseJson['message'] != 'OK') throw LoginCredentialsFailure();

      return Session.fromJson(responseJson['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      throw InternetConnectionFailure();
    }
  }
```

After sending a request instead of catching an error debugger freezes at send request point and no error is thrown.In the console of the web I've got this error message:

```
POST https://sample.com/account?email=g81%40ekcsoft.com&password=123456 net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

[image: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT]

How to handle net::ERR_TIMED_OUT error in flutter http package when send request to server?

Answer (score 0):

write like this

```
   Uri myUri = Uri.parse(url);
      var response = await http.post(
        myUri,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        },
      ).timeout(const Duration(minutes: 3));
```